# 2-year visitor visa. What is the maximum stay in the 2-year period?

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens, spouses

I have a 2-year visitor visa that is valid until 2019. I just want to clarify some things:

1. Maximum stay is 180 days. What does it mean? 180 days every visit? So I can just exit Europe and come back after 5 days and another 180 days? Or is there a limitation? Someone told me that even if I have a 2-year visa, I am only allowed to stay 6 months in any period of 12 months. Is it true? I can't find anything on UKBA site. But then I went because I don't want to jeopardize my spouse's visa application.
2. My husband is unemployed at the moment but is looking for a job. He has a house which is mortgage-free and we have combined savings of £25,000. Given that the home office requirement for unemployed is £62,500. Do you think there would be consideration? Anyone with the same case?
3. When my husband gets a job that is more than £50,000 per annum, do we need to wait for 6 months of employment before we can apply for the spouse visa?

All inputs will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a UK visa or a Schengen visa (since you mention both UK and exiting Europe)?

Comment: Visa for where? We don't read minds...

Comment: No I don't. But I can apply sciences visa once I'm in the U.K.

Comment: Sorry. Any country nearby, France, Belgium,?  Instead of going back to Canada. At least I could lessen the cost.

Comment: Hi. How about question number 2&3?

Comment: If you are a resident of Canada you will generally be unable to apply for a Schengen visa in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a UK visa only covers the UK, not the rest of Europe.

Secondly, you can stay for up to 6 months on each visit - the 12-month period rule is a myth.

That said:

> So I can just exit Europe and comeback after 5 days and another 180 days?

In theory yes, in practice no. The officer cannot think that you live in the UK through fake visits, because in that case you'll be refused entry and have your visa cancelled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It's clear now but I find it dangerous for me. I don't want an airport to airport thing.

Comment: How about number 2 & 3?

Comment: @user68480 Out of my knowledge field I'm afraid